# Why is there a syntax error on the program when v is located immediately after s? (Lex Yacc)

Tags: yacc, lex

Lex Code
...

```
%option noyywrap
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include"y.tab.h"
%}

%%
I|you|we|they|he|she|it                 return SUBJECT;
will                                    return AUX1;
did                                     return AUX2;
not                                     return NOT;
eat|drink|run|play                      return VERB1;
ate|drank|ran|played                    return VERB2;
\. return DOT;
\? return QUE;
%%
```

...

Yacc code
...

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    void yyerror(char *msg);
%}

%token  SUBJECT VERB1 DOT QUE VERB2 AUX1 AUX2 NOT

%% 
sentence:
    past DOT                {printf(" Sentence Approved "); exit(0);}
    | pastneg DOT           {printf(" Sentence Approved "); exit(0);}
    | pastint QUE           {printf(" Sentence Approved "); exit(0);}
    | fut DOT               {printf(" Sentence Approved "); exit(0);}
    | futneg DOT            {printf(" Sentence Approved "); exit(0);}
    | futint QUE            {printf(" Sentence Approved "); exit(0);}
    ;
present:
    s v          {printf(" Simple Present Tense");}
    ;
past:
    s p         {printf(" Simple Past Tense");}
    ;
pastneg:
    s x2 neg v  {printf(" Negative Simple Past Tense");}
    ;
pastint:
    x2 present  {printf(" Interrogative Simple Past Tense");}
    ;
fut:
    s x1 v      {printf(" Simple Future Tense");}
    ;
futneg:
    s x1 neg v  {printf(" Negative Simple Future Tense");}
    ;
futint:
    x1 present  {printf(" Interrogative Simple Future Tense");}
    ;
s:
    SUBJECT     {printf("Subject");}
    ;
p:
    VERB2       {printf("Verb2");}
    ;
x1:
    AUX1        {printf("will");}
    ;
x2:
    AUX2        {printf("did");}
    ;
v:
    VERB1       {printf("Verb");}
    ;
neg:
    NOT         {printf("Negative");}
    ;

%%
void yyerror(char *msg){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

There seems to be a syntax error whenever I try to run the pastint and futint. The present is also an error since VERB1 (v) is followed immediately after SUBJECT (s). I was expecting that if I input "Will he eat?" or "Did you run?" the output would be "Auxiliary Subject Verb1 Simple Past/Future Tense Sentence Accepted". But the output that I got at the moment is "Auxiliary subject Syntax error". Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: The code you have will work for your examples if you change them to lower case ("will he eat?"), but not with capitalized words as lex is case sensitive

Comment: Flex has `%option case-insensitive`, if that's your problem. But I don't see anything in the code you included which prints `Auxiliary`, so there's something you're not telling us.